# MonoDevelop "The type or namespace 'Android' could not be found"

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I've mainly been using Mono for Android via Visual Studio, but have switched over to OS X and want to use MonoDevelop.  From the main MonoDevelop menu, I click File => New => Solution.  I select Mono For Android Application, give it a name and leave the location at Users/myname/Projects by default. It creates the shell project with Activity1.cs with the basic Button.  If I try to build or debug the project, all of the using directives error out stating the The type or namespace 'Android' could not be found.  I've googled that exact message and found no matches.  I just downloaded MonoDevelop, all the required SDKs and Mono for Android yesterday on my Mac.  What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the instructions for downloading say to download Runtime OR SDK before installing MonoDevelop.  So I only downloaded SDK.  Once I installed runtime this error went away. Still can't debug to my device, but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any of those issues when I installed everything using the Xamarin installer. You might be able to fix it going to references and check if Mono.Android.dll is in red. In that case go to edit references and try to find it.

It should be in /Developer/usr/lib/mandroid/platforms

Comment: Thanks. Mono.Android is not in red in my references and I was able to find 7 different Mono.Android.dll files in my MonoDevelop installation.

Comment: I have uninstalled MonoDevelop and reinstalled.  Same problem.

Comment: Chose one of them, all of them are the same but for a different Android Framework level. It's weird though it should work...